# Pass gameobject through RPC call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to pass a gameobject through a RPC call so I can update the sprite renderer on that object for each player to change their colour. However When I try and do this i get an error saying `Write failed. Custom type not found: UnityEngine.GameObject`. Am I able to pass a gameobject as a parameter? Or is there a better way of getting the gameObject associated with a PhotonView in the scene?

NetworkPlayer.cs

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    GameObject go = gameObject;

    string[] array = {pd.m_Player.ColorTheme, pd.m_Player.Color1, pd.m_Player.Color2};
    pv.RPC(nameof(UpdateColor), RpcTarget.OthersBuffered, array, go);
}

[PunRPC]
void UpdateColor(string[] theme, GameObject go)
{  
    Debug.Log("gameObject is " + go);
}
```

Comment: that is impossible! You can not sync unity references that easily! The other sides can't know the reference since each device uses its own reference indices. Not sure how Photon solved this .. in the "good" old UNet you had to use `NetworkIdendity` components for this

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. what is a better alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

As said this is "impossible". You can sync **values** but you can not simply sync **references**. The other device has completely different reference indices so how should it know which reference belongs to the one you sent?

No photon expert so I'm not sure how exactly Photon solved this. In "good" old UNet that is what the `NetworkIdendity` component was used for.

However, since you have a PunCallback here the `UpdateColor` already **is** received on the correct `GameObject` so you already have the reference:

```
[PunRPC]
void UpdateColor(string[] theme)
{  
    Debug.Log("gameObject is " + gameObject);
}
```

Btw instead of sending an array and on the other side split/parse the array again I would rather do

```
pv.RPC(nameof(UpdateColor), RpcTarget.OthersBuffered, pd.m_Player.ColorTheme, pd.m_Player.Color1, pd.m_Player.Color2);
```

and receive

```
[PunRPC]
void UpdateColor(string theme, string color1, string color2)
{  
    pd.m_Player.ColorTheme = theme;
    pd.m_Player.Color1 = color1;
    pd.m_Player.Color2 = color2;

    Debug.Log($"Update received for {gameObject}");
}
```